# SQL Union select get max length from result

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare, maxlength

I have query against a SQL Server database:

```
Select [Surname] 
from [dbo].[customer] 

union 

Select 'Surname';
```

As result I have:

[image: SQL result]

and I want get from result `max(len( {result} ));`. If I use:

```
Select max(len([Surname])) 
from [dbo].[customer];
```

This is working correctly (in result I have 11), but I need add to compare column name.

Query:

```
Select max(len(Select [Surname] 
               from [dbo].[customer] 
               union 
               Select 'Surname'))
```

Return error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Confused ?? What is your expeected result look like ?

Comment: I change of part post. As result I want have number of maximum lenght. In example form image this is 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to

```
Select max(len([Nazwisko]))
FROM (Select [Nazwisko] from [dbo].[wlasciciel] union Select 'Surname') t
```

Comment: This work, but I don't undertand what doing 't' at end query?

Comment: It's an alias for the derived table. Most (if not all) DBMSs require it whether or not you use it anywhere.